# Types of Indexing in MySql?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have read about cluster and non cluster indexing in SQL server when i was studying .NET. In PHP i have found that there are three type of indexing like BTREE, RTREE and HEAP.

can someone tell me what is the exact answer if someone ask about type of indexing??

Answer (score 0):

MyISAM and Innodb only support B-TREE INDEX.

in MySQL manual [1], `CREATE INDEX` allow `USING HASH` :

```
index_type:
USING {BTREE | HASH}
```

but, if you use `HASH` index is created using BTREE. (it's just for compatible other DBMS)

and, InnoDB's `PRIMARY KEY` is `clustered index`. do you know what is `clustered index`?

- `UNIQUE INDEX` is just B-TREE INDEX which duplication is not allowed
- INDEXes in Memory table can use HASH INDEX [2]
- this [3] presentation gives a lot of information about clustered index in InnoDB

[1] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html

[2] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html

[3] http://www.percona.com/files/percona-live/justin-innodb-internals.pdf